# Subclipse shows my own changes as something to update to

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

After I committed, I synchronised to see if there is anything I need to get an updated. But Subclipse showed my own changes that I made as something I need to update to.

In short, I synchronised and fetched the files that I modified and Subclipse told me to update these files(my own).

Why is this happening?

Comment: Any chance you can post a screenshot, that may provide some context to understand what is going on? PS What have you tried? Is this the first time you are using the synchronize feature, or is this a long used feature that you are trying to understand why it behaved differently this time?

Comment: I checked the content of the files and they were all my recent changes so I just updated. I've been using Subclipse for... 4 years now? I had this a few times but I just moved on with it but this time, I would like to know why. So as for a screenshot, I don't think I can give you that unless this happens again very soon. As for the intention of this questions, yes I've been using this for a while but I'm trying to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I can't answer the why for you on the information provided. After many years of svn, I have moved to git for (nearly) everything (Even connecting to svn repos using https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn), so am unlikely to come across the problem anymore and be able to help. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Updating your plugin may resolve this issue